# Youtube videos via MPMoviePlayer not working in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

Ok, so I was previously playing Youtube videos using MPMOviePlayerController but now that doesn't seem to be playing in iOS 6.

How do I fix it? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on iOS 6, I found difficulty in playing Youtube videos through MPMoviePlayerController, so I found out [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lbyoutubeview) to be very useful.

This has MPMoviePlayerController only... And this would work well for Versions < iOS 6 too.

Hope it works!

Comment: Does this control gets released by Apple. Cuz people said on the same link that it's violating Youtube's TOS. Thanks

Comment: No its not released by Apple, its a 3rd Party API, but I have used this in one of my apps and it got accepted. Also, nothing would happen to your App with this code, until and unless Apple decides to do so. So it maybe a temporary solution, but at that stage I found only one solution.